# obtain session Id from cookies using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies

I am trying to learn about cookies and what all they store. Since I am an active user of Google Chrome, I was thinking of accessing the session Id of a webpage from the cookie using only Javascript. I have obtained the list of all cookies stored in the browser using `chrome.cookies.getAll()`.

However I can't understand how to access the session Id from the cookies since there is no keyword for it ?

How can I obtain the session ID from the cookies?

The code from obtaining the cookies is below :

```
<html><head>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getCookies);

var cacheMap = {};
var cookie_nameArr = [];
var cookie_valArr = [];


    function getCookies(){
        chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookies){

            for(var b in cookies){                      
            var cookieVal = cookies[b].value;
            var cookieName = cookies[b].domain;
                    cookie_nameArr.push(cookieName);
                    cookie_valArr.push(cookieVal);              
                if(!cacheMap[cookieName])
                {
                    cacheMap[cookieName] = 1;
                }
                else
                    cacheMap[cookieName]++;
    }//alert(cookie_nameArr.length + "," + cookie_valArr.length);
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
    {   
        alert(cookie_nameArr[i] + ", " + cookie_valArr[i]);

    }

});
}

</script></head>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to figure out what you are looking for. It's hard to look for a black cat in a dark room, especially if it is not there.

Open Chrome dev tools on the page you are interested in and check Resources tab. Do you see your cookie under "Cookies"? If yes, then you will be able to read it with your method. If not, then check your page url - maybe it is passed as url parameter? If not, then maybe session is used only for ajax requests? Maybe it is not used at all?

You need to find it manually first, then do it programmatically. Sessions come in all shapes and sizes, each site has its own way of implementing it. You can't build an extension that reads session for all sites.

Your approach is pretty much the way to go, just there is an easy way of inspecting objects using console instead of alert:

```
    chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "stackoverflow.com"}, function(cookies){
        console.log(cookies);
    });
```

Click on background.html link on your extensions tab and check the console.

Comment: I did look under the cookies tab for this page and yes there are some cookies present. Could you please provide me with some sample example code ?

Thanks for the infor :)

Comment: @user781022 I added the example, just try console instead of alerts.

Comment: the output obtained is :
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] 

I am guessing this is correct since there are 8 cookies under the resources tab with the stackoverflow.com domain.

Does the value of each cookie store the webpage's session ID ?

btw, really appreciate the sample code

Comment: @user781022 Click on arrows near those [Object] and you will be able to see what's inside. For stackoverflow it looks like the session is stored in `usr` cookie. As you see cookie name could be anything, it doesn't necessary has to say `SESSION`.

Comment: yes, so is there a way to find the cookie name which has the session ID and then retrieve the session ID programmatically ?

Comment: @user781022 No, that's the problem. Session cookie is just a regular cookie, it is no different from other cookies. You can only guess which one is a session cookie by looking at it.

Comment: I'm not sure but doesn't chrome.cookies.getAll() filter out session and persistent cookies? Can that be used to find out a session cookie ?...If yes, how can it be done ?

Comment: @user781022 You can make only an educated guess. Nothing stops me from using cookie "lolcat" with value "12345" as a session cookie on my site. I can set any name, any value, any expiration date I like. There is nothing that sets session cookie apart, in general case.

Comment: oo..okay...thanx for the knowledge. Appreciate it ! :)